# What is the purpose of variables.tf in Terraform root directory when using modules?

Tags: terraform, devops

I am writing some code to describe infrastructure on the AWS, and I am following Terraform best practices. To make my code more reusable and future proof, I am using modules. In the end, my code may look like this:

```
├── modules
│   └── aws_vpc
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── vars.tf
├── prod
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── terraform.tfstate
└── terraform.tfstate.backup
```

I am NOT using terraform-workspace for sake of simplicity.

Question is, what is the purpose of `variables.tf` withing the Terraform `root` directory if I can't reuse them in modules?

Idea is to have separate directories for each environment `dev`, `prod` and `qa` where I can reuse all my modules defined in `modules` directory and use environment specific variables defined in `env` directory.

There are similar discussions on the [Terraform Github pages](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5480), but as I see, such use is not encouraged.

So, what is the purpose of `variables.tf` in Terraform root directory if I can't reuse them later in modules?

I know that there is a Terragrunt which acts as a wrapper around the Terraform, but I would like to stick with the Terraform solely.

Comment: please have a look at this repo for your reference https://github.com/karan6190/Infra-provisioning

Comment: Your example is confusing. What do you consider to be the Terraform `root` directory here, `./` or `./prod`?

Comment: @EricM.Johnson depending upon the type of env you want to create, say you want to provision infra for development env the root will be  ./prod else for dev account it will be ./dev. Modules main purpose is to reuse the code.

Comment: @karansharma The confusion is that variables.tf is in `./prod` but `terraform.tfstate` is in `./`, which would indicate that Terraform was run from `./`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules have inputs and outputs. You can invoke the module multiple times, but you have to provide required inputs each time... you cannot simply rely on variables set in the calling context (although you can pass those values in as parameters).

Think of a module like a function, not an `include`. You have to pass in arguments. Modules do *not* have access to the global scope. This is generally a good programming practice... global variables lead to spaghetti code and unintended consequences. Some good reading [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).

Your module is being invoked by Terraform code in your environment directory `./prod/`, which itself has `variable` declarations in `./prod/variables.tf`. Since you're creating a directory per environment, the only way to get around sharing data or resources at this top level is to copy/paste, or to symlink files like so:

```
├── modules
│   └── aws_vpc
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── vars.tf
├── prod
│   ├── global_variables.tf (symlink from ./shared/global_variables.tf)
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── shared
│   └── global_variables.tf
├── terraform.tfstate
└── terraform.tfstate.backup
```

Note that unless you actually want to change these values at runtime with `-var` or `-var-file`, you might actually want to be using [locals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html). I used to use variables with default values instead of locals, but if the value will never change for that environment it makes sense to use locals instead.

Answer (score 0):

In any given *Terraform* dir, I don't think about any `.tf` files as having any particular function apart from giving you some visibility into how you've broken out your resources and/or arranged your code. So `main.tf` and `variables.tf` could be consolidated into 1 file without any loss of function.

In your setup, your `variables.tf` would have a set of vars that each had a `default` value (or else `terraform x` commands would prompt for their values). Alternatively, you could omit the `default` values and instead create a `terraform.tfvars` file that set values for each var.

In this setup with separate dirs for each environment (prod, test, dev, etc.), I prefer to use `terraform.tfvars` as I find it easier to do diffs and I know that the only thing that I need to modify with any given env is the `terraform.tfvars` file.

For example, `cidr_block` may be a variable that you specify for each env, and then pass to the `aws_vpc` module. *prod* may be 192.168.0.0/16 while *test* might have 10.1.0.0/16.

As for the module, although it may seem like all of the vars are repeats/duplicates with the code in the environment dirs, it's not a given. For example, you may have a var in your env code that is a boolean that is passed into your module as an input that the module then uses to make certain 'decisions'.